# Create a Collection which is an union of several collections (EmberJS)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to display a list which is the union of a list of lists.

### My models

I got two hasMany relations linking a movie to a library

```
+---------+  hasMany   +---------+  hasMany   +-------+
| Library | ---------> | Storage | ---------> | Movie |
+---------+            +---------+            +-------+
```

Javascript :

```
App.Library = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr(),
    storages : DS.hasMany('storage', {async:true})
});

App.Storage = DS.Model.extend({
    hostname : DS.attr(),
    login : DS.attr(),
    password : DS.attr(),
    name : DS.attr(),
    movies: DS.hasMany('movie', {async:true})
});

App.Movie = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr()
    duration : DS.attr()
});
```

The library is loaded in my AppController :

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  data: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('library', 1);
  }.property()
});
```

### The problem

What i'm trying to do is display a list of all the movies of my library, sorted by name. I tried something like that, which is not working :

```
App.LibraryController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  sortProperties : [ 'name' ],
  sortAscending : true,

  model: function() {
    var storages = this.get('controllers.application.data.storages');
    if (storages) {
      return storages.mapBy('cpls').reduce(function(accum, items) {
        return accum.pushObjects(items);
      }, Ember.ArrayController.create({}));
    }
    else {
      return [];
    }
  }.property('controllers.application.data.storages.@each')
});
```

But this approach has several issues :

- Obviously, it's not working
- If a single movie is added or removed, the entire Array has to be rebuilt instead of just modifying one entry
- The property should depend on `controllers.application.data.storages.@each.movies.@each` but EmberJS does not support adding selectors after a @each (see the note at the end of [computed properties and aggregate data with @each](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/))

I need some pointers here, anybody knows how to solve this problem properly ?

---

Edit :

I found this gist which is relevant to my problem [An implementation of a merged array in Ember.js that combines items from multiple source arrays](https://gist.github.com/sebastianseilund/6096696)

Comment: Did you consider querying the store for movies directly? `store.find(App.Movie)`. This will give you the recordArray that will keep updating as soon as you add more movies to the store.

Comment: This will list all the movies, including those not in the current library.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Sorry I can't help. I'm not sure what would be a good solution for this. I'm not familiar with the domain model and I'm not sure what the storage is doing, but, would it be possible to denormalize it and add movies directly to a library? Maybe the storage makes sense server side, but in the context of the app it might not be needed (just a wild guess). I often have a different model client side that deals with a smaller context (e.g. for one user, region, denormalized, flattened relationships, etc)

Comment: IMHO this is not the cleanest approach but clearly the most efficient. That's what i ended up doing, Thanks for the input !

Comment: I think changing the structure is good when IF/WHEN it makes sense for the application domain, but it feels wrong to do it because of a limitiation of the framework.  Other libraries have a selectMany or flatten method to do exactly this. I'm sorry I can't provide a better answer :(